# Why does LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(Context context) require context as a parameter?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, localbroadcastmanager

If I am able to register a receiver like so:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("myStringFilter"));
```

and send out a broadcast like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("myStringFilter");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(new Activity()).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

why even require Context for getInstance? If I can just say `new Activity()` and it still works, what is the point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now, `LocalBroadcastManager` uses the supplied `Context` for is to call `getApplicationContext()` on it. While `new Activity()` may work at present wherever you tested it, I would not rely upon that behavior necessarily working on all past/present/future versions of Android.

`LocalBroadcastManager` needs a `Context` in order to work with a `Handler` and `Looper` for the main application thread, and it uses `Application` for that (rather than some other `Context`) to prevent memory leaks.

You are welcome to examine [the source code to `LocalBroadcastManager`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-cts-7.1_r6/core-utils/java/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.java) to learn more about its inner workings.