# How to safely send data from a service to running activity

Tags: android

Lets say I have a String test = "value" available in a service and want to send it to my **running** mainactivity.
How does one send that data safely?
Im looking for the most simple example possible, where the data can not be seen by other apps.
When I look at intents it says:

> A broadcast is a message that any app can receive. The system delivers
>   various broadcasts for system events, such as when the system boots up
>   or the device starts charging. You can deliver a broadcast to >>>>other
>   apps<<< by passing an Intent to sendBroadcast() or
>   sendOrderedBroadcast().

However I want to send it to my app only as it contains private data.
In my service I tried:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.notification_intent), "6");
startActivity(intent);
```

Where MainActivity.class is the class that should receive the intent, but in this way I get:

```
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

How can I safely send data from a service to an activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: How do I send data from an Android service to my activity?

A: You have several alternatives:

**1. Use intents:**

[How to get data from service to activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125241/how-to-get-data-from-service-to-activity)

Send msg from service:

```
private static void sendMessageToActivity(Location l, String msg) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("GPSLocationUpdates");
    // You can also include some extra data.
    intent.putExtra("Status", msg);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelable("Location", l);
    intent.putExtra("Location", b);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Register to receive message in activity:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(
            mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("GPSLocationUpdates"));
```

Custom message receiver in activity:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get extra data included in the Intent
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("Status");
        Bundle b = intent.getBundleExtra("Location");
        lastKnownLoc = (Location) b.getParcelable("Location");
        ...
```

I would *NOT* characterize this as "unsafe" - it can be a perfectly reasonable approach.

**2. Have the activity bind to the service**

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services

Service:

```
public class LocalService extends Service {
    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();
    ...
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }
```

Activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Bind to LocalService
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
        bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        ...
     @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            unbindService(connection);
            mBound = false;
        ...
    /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
        private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }
    ...
    // To use the service, your client would call mService.someMethod()...
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but example 1 is probably your best bet.

Here's a tutorial that might help give you more details/more ideas:

**Basics Of Services In Android**:

- [Part 1: Basics](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/basics-of-services-in-android-part-1/)
- [Part 2: Binding services to an activity](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/binding-services-to-activity-part-2/)
- [Part 3: Using Messenger](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/bound-service-using-messenger-in-android-part-3/)

---

> https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts
>
> **Android provides three ways for apps to send broadcast:**
>
> - The sendOrderedBroadcast(Intent, String) method sends broadcasts to one receiver at a time.
> - sendBroadcast(Intent) method sends broadcasts to all receivers in an undefined order. This is called a Normal Broadcast. This is more
>     efficient, but means that receivers cannot read results from other
>     receivers, propagate data received from the broadcast, or abort the
>     broadcast.
> - LocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast method sends broadcasts to receivers that are in the same app as the sender. If you don't need to
>     send broadcasts across apps, use local broadcasts. The implementation
>     is much more efficient (no interprocess communication needed) and you
>     don't need to worry about any security issues related to other apps
>     being able to receive or send your broadcasts.

Additionally:

> https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#restrict-broadcasts-permissions
>
> **Restricting broadcasts with permissions**
>
> Permissions allow you to restrict broadcasts to the set of apps that hold certain permissions. You can enforce restrictions on either
>   the sender or receiver of a broadcast.
>
> **Sending with permissions**
>
> When you call sendBroadcast(Intent, String) or sendOrderedBroadcast(Intent, String, BroadcastReceiver, Handler, int,
>   String, Bundle), you can specify a permission parameter. Only
>   receivers who have requested that permission with the tag in their
>   manifest (and subsequently been granted the permission if it is
>   dangerous) can receive the broadcast. For example, the following code
>   sends a broadcast:

Personally, I don't see any "security" issue at all with simply using an intent.

But if you want or need to, you *can* use the above techniques to further lock down communications.

'Hope that helps!

Comment: "Security consciousness" is a Good Thing.  There are *LOTS* of things you're justified in being paranoid about.  But frankly, I don't thnk some other app attempting to register to read one of your intents is one of them :(  Nevertheless, Android gives you several options .  Please see my updates above.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer. I have a question what is context in : 'LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);'

Comment: Application Context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22355974/3135317